# Excel - How to migrate rows of data from multiple sheets into a consolidated sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, collaboration

I am creating an Excel template wherein many people are entitled to encode their daily movements. They wanted each person to have their own sheet in the workbook to avoid editing others' accounts. However, I have to track each of their movements and compare the output from different stages. Is it possible to automatically migrate data from multiple sheets to a separate consolidated sheet? Whenever someone adds rows of data, it will automatically appear in one sheet?

Comment: Many things are possible in excel, but based on your description, I would think there are better turn-key solutions out there.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you would describe the format/range of those individual sheets and in which way you want all those to show up in the consolidated sheet.

Comment: Are you looking for [Combine data from multiple sheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/combine-data-from-multiple-sheets-dd7c7a2a-4648-4dbe-9a11-eedeba1546b4)?

Comment: It is also possible to write a macro in VBA, but you would have to learn VBA.

Comment: Protect WorkSheet for each user?